# Present count of deleted records

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have some simple code that deletes every record in a table smaller than a certain date. I am using PDO as db access method.

**How can I see** *(and hence report to the user)* **how many records that were actually deleted in the database?**

I was thinking transaction (count records to be deleted --> execute delete --> if everything was OK - present counted records to user), but there has to be an easier way, no?

It seems that execute only returns a boolean value that will only give me an indication of success.

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-06-22 12:00:00');

try{
    $datestring = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dbh = getConnected($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM sometable WHERE date_and_time < '$datestring'");
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "$rd records deleted"; // where $rd = number of records deleted returned from the query
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
    error_log($e->getMessage().PHP_EOL, 3, "errors.log");
}

$dbh -> connection = null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

will give you number of rows affected

[PDO rowcount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [affected_rows function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

```
printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I initially forgot to mention that I am using PDO and not mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

If that is mysqli being used (its not stated or clear), in your case, do $stmt->affected_rows

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated my question to reflect the access method used (PDO).

Comment: Ah, then use the answer by @Undefined_variable